# How to change an Object from Solid to Hollow in Blender 3.1.2?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

As someone new to Blender I have an object (STL) I've imported into Blender that I want to create a mold for that I can then 3D print.

I therefor want to encase it in a larger version of itself (split in at least two pieces to create the mold) then turn this interior object I've imported hollow to create it's shape inside the mold encasing it.

This is easy in TinkerCad by simply highlighting the object then selecting the Hollow* icon but how do you do change an object from Solid to Hollow in Blender 3.1.2  then group it together with the mold thereby creating it's shape in the form of a hollow in inside the mold?

Comment: is the object symmetrical? if so you could delete the other half then apply a *Solidify Modifier* and a *Mirror Modifier* otherwise there is no automatic way to do this afaik in blender other than do this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/235874/142292

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/subtracting-geometry https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-an-empty-object/